# How can I create a Wi-Fi network from my Galaxy Tab with no internet access?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-tab, wifi-hotspot

What I am trying to do is to connect an iPad to a Samsung Galaxy Tab via Wireless LAN. What I don't need is an internet connection.

I also only have an Samsung Galaxy Tab Wifi. I can access the Hotspot Options via a shortcut, but it tells me that I need a SIM to do that.

Is there any way to create a local WLAN network broadcast by the Tab?

Comment: Seems like nobody has any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The app [ZT-180 Adhoc Switcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.hal9000.zt180_adhoc_switcher) works with a **rooted** P1010 tab according to [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=838136&page=7) thread on xda-developers, and as far as I know, iPad can create ad-hoc connections. Haven't tested this so use at your own risk.